# Adjust manual focus for sharper images with Sony RX0,for aerial photography

Tags: sony, manual-focus, manual-mode, aerial-photography

I am taking photos around 80m altitudes (with Sony RX0) with a moving drone,Shutter Speed is set to 1/1000 to prevent blurs,I want to take sharp images with manual focus,how should I adjust settings ?

Comment: How are you controlling the manual focus on an airborne drone?

Comment: I want to adjust the focus in the ground and then use during the flight, the thing is autofocus takes 0.5s-1s to focus

Comment: @user818117 so you're pre-configuring the camera, flying, taking the photo, coming back down and then checking the rules and re-configuring as needed? Generally, with making an image sharp just make sure to shoot around Appature 8-11 or higher, this will give you a large depth of field and give sharper images.

Comment: @Matthew the thing is RX0 has fixed aperture as it is written in the descriptions `F-NUMBER (MAXIMUM APERTURE)
F4.0 (Fixed)`

Comment: @user818117 https://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/support/res/manuals/4690/46902871M.pdf this is likely your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a ring-stop lens to increase the DOF; but, it will be at the expense of the exposure. You might have to compensate with the ISO to regain sharpness loss due to vibration.

A ring-stop lens is simply a "washer" (a disk with a hole in the middle.) You can make a few and see which one suits your purposes. It works the same as squinting helps some people who need glasses but refuse to wear them to see detail more clearly. It's an outboard supplementary "aperture ring" in fact.

Use opaque paper (black is suggested) into which you punch a hole. Place the paper over the lens with the hole centred. You may have to tape it in place.

Start with a hole about the size of the aperture when viewed dead-on. How did it work? No? Try one slightly smaller to see if that result is better, and so on.

There will be an optimal size for the hole. Normally, you can get to half the diameter before image artifacts start to accumulate.

Good luck.

Comment: A Barlow mounts before the camera lens. It is has negative power i.e. a convex lens.  A Barlow is used to increase the focal length of the camera lens. Most elongate the focal length 1.5X or 2X. Thus the results are more magnification (telephoto effect). A longer focal length reduces depth of field. The 80 meter subject distance will be at infinity. Focus the camera before launch on a distant object. To maximize depth-of-field pre-set focus to the hyper focal distance.

Comment: @AlanMarcus Thanks. I used a generic term until I locate the exact term.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but if you decide to use ring-stops it may help in deciding maximum depth of field.
https://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/focus.htm